# conditional values for each combobox in extjs grid

Tags: extjs, combobox

I have a EditorGridPanel which contains two columns, country and state, each being implemented as a combobox. User can add as many rows as he/she wants. I have a list of countries and cities in in the corresponding stores and everything is working fine now. I want to add one enhancement to it for which i need some help. Currently i am loading all the cities in the combobox, instead of that, i want to load only the cities from selected country. I cant think of a way to do this, appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

You should modify state's store after you select some country in the first list.
For example try to subscribe on the beforeedit event of the grid editor plugin and load only states you want.

You could access editor of the column using: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-method-getEditor

And here is the event I mentioned: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-beforeedit

Comment: Thanks, i think i can use the before edit event and load only the required information. Will accept it after completing the code

Comment: I'm having the same trouble in my app... How can I access the store of the cell editor to change combobox items?